# python unpack binary data

Tags: python, linux, debian

i am writing a rlm_python module for radius which grabs location from "Accouting-Request" packet

however, the location is on binary format,

```
 "\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024"
```

when i try to unpack using struct

```
[root@server ~]# python 
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 16:39:10) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import *
>>> unpack('hhl',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024" )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
struct.error: unpack str size does not match format
```

any idea, how i can unpack this data?

Comment: You have *octal*, not binary data.

Comment: any idea how to convert this?

Comment: Compare `calcsize('l')`, `calcsize('=l')`, `calcsize('i')`, etc. (where `calcsize` is `struct.calcsize`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is eight bytes long but `unpack` may not expect that (the size is platform-dependent unless you use modifiers).

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 16:39:10) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import *
>>> unpack('hhl',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024" )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
struct.error: unpack str size does not match format
>>> unpack('=hhl',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024" )
(5889, 5378, 335620865)
```

From [`struct.unpack` docs](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/struct.html?highlight=struct%20unpack#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

> If the first character is not one of these, '@' is assumed.
>   Native size and alignment are determined using the C compiler’s sizeof expression. This is always combined with native byte order. 
>   Standard size depends only on the format character; see the table in the Format Characters section.

Comment: thanks brain, appreciated, actually this location/data is coming from the option82 in DHCP field, so i was hoping it to be a string...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = "\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024"
>>> data
'\x01\x17\x02\x15\x01+\x01\x14'
>>> len(data)
8
>>> struct.calcsize('hhl')
16
>>> struct.calcsize('!hhl')
8
>>> struct.unpack('!hhl',data)
(279, 533, 19595540)
```

Depending on your architecture, the size of some elements may change unless you modify the constructor.